# RevenueCat IAP - Testing without Google Play Console credentials

Tags: flutter, google-play-console, revenuecat

I would like to know if I can test RevenueCat IAP without setting up a Google Play Console account. I have submitted my app for review, but it is currently taking a long time to get reviewed and accepted. Is there any way I can test RevenueCat without Google Play Console?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a Google Play Console account to test the app flow with RevenueCat and unfortunately it can take some time for a closed track to get approved. You can also test on an internal track first, there shouldn't be a wait period for approvals. Google help center for reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en